# Does 'responsible' in 'responsible for' function as a verb or an adverb?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentence "you are responsible for his demise", does 'responsible' function as a verb with object his demise, or does it function as an adverb modifying 'are'?

Answer (score 3):

"Responsible" is an adjective, part of the adjective phrase "responsible for his demise". That adjective phrase is the predicate of the copulative verb "are".
"For his demise" is a preposition phrase that explains "responsible"